# On or with the meanings?

Tags: prepositions

Once in a while, I see a few words that I am not totally solid on the meanings.

Or

Once in a while, I see a few words that I am not totally solid with the meanings.

I don't know which one is better. They both sound okay to me.

Comment: They are both wrong. What do you want to say? You mean you disagree with the meanings of some words you come across?

Comment: Not 100% sure of the meaning of the word I saw in a book.